# Domain object to entity model, EF loses tracking issue (DDD)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, automapper, clean-architecture

I'm trying to follow DDD but feel like I'm missing something. My solution is like:

- Domain project having `Order` and `OrderItem` classes (these classes have instance methods containing some business logic like `CanChangeOrder` etc.)
- Application layer
- Infrastructure project with EF Core i.e. a wrapper around database tables (like `Orders` & `OrderItems`)
- Web project - Controllers

[image]

**Here's I need your advice:**

Say a customer edits his order (adds 1 new item, changes an existing item quantity and removes two items).

In (**infrastructure project**) I fetch the `Order` and `OrderItems`, convert to Order domain object (using `automapper`) and returns to the caller method of application layer.

```
var dbOrder = await _dbContext.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId == orderId && o.DeletedDateTimeUtc == null).Include(o => o.OrderItems.Where(i => i.DeletedDateTimeUtc == null)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    
var domainOrder = _mapper.Map<Domain.Entities.Order>(dbOrder);
                return Result.Ok(domainOrder);
```

(**Application layer**) Order domain object has an instance method, to verify can order be edited. If true, I add, edit, remove items in the Order object, now send that modified Order object (including OrderItems) to the persistence layer (Infrastructure project).

```
var orderResult = await _orderRepo.Get(request.OrderId);

if (!orderResult.Value.CanOrderBeUpdated())
  return Result.Fail("Sorry, order can not be changed now.");
else
   update domain model based on the user request

_orderRepo.Update(domainOrderModel)
```

(**Infrastructure layer**) Here I again convert my `Order` domain model to EF Core entity `Order` model. But all `OrderItem` are treated a new items as EF Core has no tracking for existing items resulting new rows in `OrderItems` table. To avoid this I place a check in `Update` method below:

```
    public void Update(Domain.Entities.Order order)
            {
                var dbOrder = _mapper.Map<Infrastructure.Entities.Order>(order);

                // to instruct ef to insert or update an order item
                foreach (var item in dbOrder.OrderItems)
                {
                    if (item.OrderId > 0)
                       _dbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
        
                _dbContext.Orders.Update(dbOrder);
            }
```

I feel this approach not efficient (do you?), please advice improvements.

Thank you

Comment: Why is the `domain` model different from the `ef core` model?

Comment: should I treat ef core model as domain model?

Comment: separate domain models from ef core model, ensures SOC and domain logic in domain layer.

Comment: It depends on your project, how much complexity there is and whether there was a reason why you couldn't use a model to implement DDD. I personally use Domain Models as a Database Model to reduce the complexity and ease of work, and I did not have any problems.

Comment: By ensuring SOC, do you mean being persistence-ignorance? In that case, fluent mapping leaves your domain objects as POCO and you wouldn't be concerned about that. You can use your domain model as your persistent model.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel this approach not efficient (do you?), please advice improvements.

The answer depends on how you consider your persistence layer.

##### ORM as a domain persistance library

The concept of repository was invented before the generalization of ORM libraries. Back then, the infrastructure layer would be the place were developpers would turn OOP (`Order.Update()`) into SQL (`UPDATE Orders SET ... WHERE id = ...`). Actually ORM libs were build after developpers tried to generalize the object repository pattern they implemented atop of their SQL infrastructure.

If the purpose of your infrastructure layer is to unconditionally store and restore your domain state, and you don't really care on how the data is structured in the database (domain first), then yes this is an highly inefficient approach. In this case, use EF entities as your domain model and let EF itself (the library) be your infrastructure layer. The DbContext acts both as a Repository and a Unit-of-work:

```cs
namespace Domain;
public class UpdateOrderUseCase(MyDbContext database) // .NET 8 notation for consistency
{
  public void Execute(UpdateOrderDto payload)
  {
    var order = database.Orders.Find(payload.id) ?? throw new NotFoundException();
    order.CanUpdate || throw new ConflictException();

    // update order from payload

    database.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

NOTE: the code above is an intention example, mind your actual implementations.

This will put some constraints on your domain model though: adding business features might be difficult with EF, as the library need entities to translate in the relational world. You will probably end up having an anemic domain model and putting some business rules in service classes. Also this will leak some RDBMS concepts in the business layer which might or might not (depending on your context) be a problem.

##### ORM as a mediation layer between business and infrastructure

If you want to have a structurally different persistence schema than your business model, and want a non-anemic domain model, then you need those conversions. Since you will have structural differences from the business model and the persistence model, it will have more percieved value to do this mapping though.

Example of stupid code that allows to store order details and items details in separate databases, ommiting the 2-phase commit pattern and transactions for readability:

```cs
namespace Infrastructure;
public class OrderRepository(
  OrderDbContext orders,
  OrderItemsDbContext items,
) : IOrderRepository
{
  public void Update(Domain.Entities.Order order)
  {
    var oder = orders.FindById(order.Id) ?? throw NotFoundException();
    // update order details
    orders.SaveChanges();

    items.Items.Where(item => item.OrderId == order.id).ExecuteDelete();
    items.Items.AddRange(order.Items.ProjectTo<ItemsEntity>());
    items.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

One benefit of this approach is that you may hide your infrastructure details from the domain layer (for instance your surrogate keys) so your application is less dependent on EF / RDBMS. Altough that's a high price to pay for versatility if you're not in the middle of a persistance infrastructure change context.

##### The value object problem

One of the problems you are facing is caused by the fact that EF currently only manipulates entities (objects with an identifier). But in the domain world, items do not have natural keys. They would rather have been modeled as value objects:

```cs
namespace Domain;

public class Order
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

In current EF version you could look into [Owned Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities), to have the lib do the upsert for you, based on the item values. But owned entities have drawbacks since they still have hidden identifiers behind the scene.

Fortunately [EF 8 will be able to support complex types as value objects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-rc1/).